# Image breaking layout in Foundation 5 by not being responsively resized

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

**Summary**
Foundation 5 handles content images (as opposed to background images added to a div) to be responsive if the width is smaller than image width.

I added a sticky footer that has a responsive height. This addition because of the display is now preventing Foundation 5 to properly display content on the page below the width of the largest image on the page.

**Intent**
Modify the CSS of the responsive footer so that it does not interfere with how images are handled by Foundation 5.

---

There is an image that is breaking my layout and now the text of the text is not bound by the device width. The problem seems to be coming from wrapping the content in a div that was added to give it a [responsive sticky footer](http://timothy-long.com/responsive-sticky-footer/). This class is the problem that needs to be modified.

```
.container { 
  display: table; 
  height: 100%; 
  width: 100%; 
  margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

At this point the problem is already present. The header wrapped in that does fine. But I then put the content into a div that looks like this

```
<div class="block push">
```

Those classes are also necessary for the responsive sticky footer. The classes have these rules

```
.block { 
  display: table-row; 
  height: 1px; 
}

.push { 
  height: auto; 
}
```

Here is an image of my site with normal display (i commented out the image)

[image]

But here it is with the image, as you can see, the text extends to the length of the image

[image]

This is my current HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="large-12 columns">
    <h1>Bruxzir Testimonials</h1>
    <a href="#Submit-Testimonial" title="Submit Your BruxZir Testimonial" class="button">Click Here to Submit Your BruxZir Testimonial</a>
    <ul id="testimonials">  
      <li>
        <p>&quot;This patient's anterior case came out great. I just wanted to share the before and after photos with you. BruxZir keeps surprising us.&quot;</p>
        <p><img src="/assets/img/content/images-bruxzir-zirconia-dental-crown/testimonial-case/before-after.jpg" alt="bruxzir anterior case" /></p>
        <span class="author">&ndash; Janet S., DDS, Oaklawn, IL</span><br />
        <span>Ceramics by <a href="http://www.pcdl-usa.com/" target="_blank">Precision Ceramics Dental Laboratory</a>, Montclair, CA</span>
      </li>
    </ul>  
  </div>
</div>
```

In the inspector in Firefox I tested passing rules to it and it was taking widths in `px`

[image: px]

but does not seem to take them in percentages.

[image: percentages]

Not sure what I could be missing here. I currently have this page on a demo server at

http://windev.jgallardo.me/pages/testimonials-bruxzir-zirconia-dental-crown/index.aspx

Comment: could have picked nicer images. Damn...

Comment: @koenp i cropped it out since it was so ugly. Dental before and afters are never pretty :/

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after some edits here's what I've got. If you remove two CSS rules, you'll be responsive. They are:

display: table-row css rule on the

```
div.mainContent {
  display: table-row;
}
```

and

```
div.container {
  display: table;
}
```

Delete those two, and then check how the design responds to browser width.

Comment: I tried the first suggestion by disabling in the editor, but did not work initially nor when I removed the class from the div. But the width seems to be fine on the other pages. when that image is removed, all is well. so the display:table on the container is also the problem. Either way forcing me to choose between responsive images or responsive sticky footer. I am thinking the best solution will target the image itself because otherwise the layout is expanding to fit around it?

Comment: I'm not totally sure I understand the end result you want. Explain what you mean by sticky images vs sticky footer.

Comment: I am using the Foundation 5 framework which by default has CSS rules to work with images responsively. But I added the sticky footer, and those classes interfere with how images are handled. My desired outcome would be to preserve the way images are handled. But to add the sticky footer that has a responsive height based on the content inside of it.

Comment: okay, edited my answer. I think that's what you're going for.

Comment: The problem seems to not be much a problem when viewing on an iPhone. The mistake I made was trusting my browser on my desktop to display what I would see at a similar width. And this was accomplished by adding `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />` in the `<head>`. Thanks for all of your help.